# Melhor prática para cliente escolher formato de resposta (JSON / XML)

Tags: php, request, rotas, silex, response

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor prática de codificação que permita o cliente definir o formato de resposta para a requisição que ele fez, que também pode incluir filtros, condições, ordenações, etc...

Fiz um pequeno modelo para a resposta, não sei se é a melhor prática, mas funciona (conselhos são bem vindos). Codifiquei no Middleware after();

PS.: A escolha do formato será dinâmico após contruir o código do request.

Agora sobre a requisição. Imaginei codificar no Middleware before(). Qual a melhor forma de se fazer?

Segue o código:

**index.php**

```
<?php

define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
chdir(ROOT);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'src/Config/bootstrap.php';
require 'src/Config/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$app = new Application();

$app['serializer'] = function(){
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    return new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
};

$app['debug'] = true;

/*$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app){
  $request->query->
});*/

$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
  //var_dump($response);
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  return $response;
});

return $app;
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$app->mount('/classificados', require 'src/App/Controllers/ClassificadosController.php');
```

**ClassificadosController.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$classificados = $app['controllers_factory'];

$classificados->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $post = array(
        'title' => 'Titulo',
        'body'  => 'corpo',
    );

    $serializeContent = $app['serializer']->serialize($post, 'xml');
    return new Response($serializeContent, 200);
});

return $classificados;
```

Qual a melhor forma de montar uma lógica para dinamizar o formato de resposta (json ou xml) para o cliente?

**UPDATE**

Refatorei meu código pela resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento, tive a idéia de sempre retornar um json do Controller e no after(), se tiver sido solicitado um xml deserializar o retorno e serializar em um novo response no formato xml, se for solicitado um json retornaria o próprio response sem realizar esse procedimento, com a intenção de abstrair esse procedimento de cada rota? Será que fica muito custoso pro servidor?

Ficou assim:

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$app = new Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app['formatSerialize'] = function($format){
  $app['formatSerialize'] = $format;
};

$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
  $app['formatSerialize'] = (array_key_exists('xml', $request->query->all()) == 1) ? 'xml' : 'json';
});

$app->after(function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
  if ($app['formatSerialize'] == 'xml'){
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()), array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()));

    $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    $serializeContent = $serializer->serialize($data, $app['formatSerialize']);

    $resp = new Response($serializeContent, $response->getStatusCode());
    $resp->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    return $resp;
  }
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $response;
});

return $app;
```

**ClassificadosController.php**

```
<?php

$classificados = $app['controllers_factory'];

$classificados->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $post = array(
        'title' => 'Titulo',
        'body'  => 'corpo',
    );

    return $app->json($post, 200);
});

return $classificados;
```

Essa deserialização e re-serialização é muito custoso?

Comment: Uma boa prática é deixar e tipo de retorno sendo informado pelo header da aplicação. No caso quem está fazendo a requisição, deverá informa no header Content-Type application/json ou application/xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melhor prática eu acho que *"não tem"*, depende muito do conforto do que quer passar para o cliente, todavia recomendo experimentar algumas dessas

1. Pode definir uma rota para cada:

   ```php
   $classificados->get('/xml', function() use ($app) {
   //...Coloque a execução para serializer como Xml aqui
   ```

   Json:

   ```php
   $classificados->get('/json', function() use ($app) {
   //...Coloque a execução para serializer como Json aqui
   ```
2. Ou pode usar o `Accept:` header, neste caso vai depender do software do lado do cliente enviar o header `Accept` junto com a requisição, por exemplo Ajax, ou então um aplicativo Mobile, para acesso direto via browser não vai funcionar.

   Para usar basta que o seu Ajax (se usar algo assim), faça isso:

   ```javascript
   xhr.open("GET", url, true);    // async
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml"); //Requisita XML
   xhr.onreadystatechange = OnStateChange;
   xhr.send(null);
   ```

   Se for um aplicativo Mobile que usa Java ou C++ (Android) ou Object-c ou Switft (iOS/Mac) vai depender de como faz, todavia não é algo dificil de descobrir, e no php deve fazer assim:

   ```php
   //$request se refere a classe `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`
   $contentType = $request->headers->get('Accept');

   if (strpos($contentType, 'application/json') === 0) {
       //Serialize Json
   } else if (strpos($contentType, '/xml') !== false) {
       //Serialize Xml
   }
   ```
3. Ou pode até resolver com um simples uso de GET, algo como `http://site/?type=json` ou `http://site/?type=xml`:

   ```php
   switch ($request->query->get('type')) {
       case 'json':
           //Serialize Json
       break;
       case 'xml':
           //Serialize Xml
       break;
   }
   ```
4. Ou pode até criar uma rota que simule um arquivo:

   ```php
   //Acesse via http://site/api.xml
   $classificados->get('/api.xml', function() use ($app) {
       //...Coloque a execução para serializer como Xml aqui
   ```

   Json:

   ```php
   //Acesse via http://site/api.json
   $classificados->get('/api.json', function() use ($app) {
      //...Coloque a execução para serializer como Json aqui
   ```

   Ou também pode usar algo como:

   ```php
   //Acesse via http://site/api.json ou http://site/api.xml
   $app->get('/api.{format}', function($format) use ($app) {
       switch ($format) {
           case 'json':
               //Serialize Json
           break;
           case 'xml':
               //Serialize Xml
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Guilherme. Não sei se entendei a Opção 2, eu vou pegar qual o "Content-Type" foi requisitado pelo cliente? Como ele, o Cliente, informaria isso?

Comment: @LeoFelipe eu digitei errado, vou corrigir

Comment: entendi agora, pra mim esta forma, da Opção 2, seria a mais "bonita" de se codificar. Por enquanto que estou fazendo exemplos simples e testando direto no browser, irei usar a Opção 3, mas para projetos futuros, usarei a Opção 2 mesmo. Vou atualizar como refiz meu código. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @LeoFelipe eu também gosto muito da opção 2, mas ainda sim eu daria preferencia para opção 1 ou 3, acaso venha a implementar sistema de Cache, porque assim evita conflitos ;)

Comment: Hmm.... Entendi, boa cara. Vem cá, acabei esquecendo de perguntar. Você acha que o processo de deserialização e logo após um nova serialização é muito custoso pro server? Com a intenção de abstrair isso no Controller, acabei implementando esse processo. Coloquei o Update.

Comment: Mas porque precisa serializar e deserialisar na mesma chamada?

Comment: Só pra retirar essa responsabilidade ( de 1 linha ) ao retorno de cada rota. Então toda rota sempre retornaria um json, se o formato solicitado fosse json não faria a deserialização e reserialização, mas se o que foi solicitado fosse um xml, aí ocorreria esse processo, pra poder transformá-lo em xml. Só não sei se seria muito custoso com grandes dados, pois não há como eu testar aqui.

Comment: Acho que está bem confuso o porque de fazer tudo na mesma requisição, vou dar uma olhada melhor no Silex e tentar entender a necessidade do before e after, assim que possivel eu volto.

Comment: Para deixar mais intuitivo a solução 3, não poderia passar a informação como extensão da URL mesmo? `/site/classificados.json` ou `/site/classificados.xml`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pronto, obrigado pela dica ;)

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [Documentação do Silex 2](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#view-handlers), você poderá usar o método `Silex\Application::view` para definir a configuração de apresentação de dados para o usuário.

```
$app->view(function (array $controllerResult, Request $request) use ($app) {

    $acceptHeader = $request->headers->get('Accept');

    $bestFormat = $app['negotiator']->getBestFormat($acceptHeader, array('json', 'xml'));

    if ('json' === $bestFormat) {
        return new JsonResponse($controllerResult);
    }

    if ('xml' === $bestFormat) {
        return $app['serializer.xml']->renderResponse($controllerResult);
    }

    return $controllerResult;
});
```

Esse método view trata-se de um interceptor de respostas. Ele fará com que a resposta seja dada ao usuário de acordo como parâmetro `Accept` presente nos headers, mas você poderá personalizar para fazer isso via parâmetro GET.

Crei que da forma que você fez não está errada, mas já que existe um método específico para tratar apenas da apresentação, como mostrado acima, eu optaria por utilizá-lo.